# Misunderstanding of notation of tangent maps

Tags: differential-geometry, notation

Im getting mad with the notation related to tangent bundles and so. Im following the book *Analysis II* of Amann and Escher, where the main discussed issue appear in page 270.

---

Some definitions: let $M\subset\Bbb R^n$ a submanifold of dimension $m$, then $$\begin{align}T_pM:=\{&(v)_p\in T_p\Bbb R^n:\\&\quad\exists\epsilon>0\exists\gamma\in C^1((-\epsilon,\epsilon),\Bbb R^n)\text{ such that }{\rm im}(\gamma)\subset M,\gamma(0)=p,\dot\gamma(0)=v\}\tag1\end{align}$$

where $T_p\Bbb R^n:=\{(p,v):v\in\Bbb R^n\}$ and $(v)_p:=(p,v)$. And for some differentiable $f:M\to Y$ is defined

$$T_pf:T_pM\to T_{f(p)}Y,\quad (p,v)\mapsto (f(p),\partial f(p)v)\tag2$$

Also is described a chain rule for tangent maps that reads

$$T_p(f\circ g)=T_{g(p)}f\circ T_p g\tag3$$

Suppose $\varphi$ is a chart of $M$ around $p$, thus is defined as in $(2)$, that is

$$T_p\varphi:T_pM\to T_{\varphi(p)}V$$

for some $V\subset\Bbb R^m$.

---

My confusion starts from the representation of $(T_p\varphi)v$ (for some $v\in T_pM$). It is written as

$$(T_p\varphi)v=\sum_{k=1}^m v_ke_k\tag4$$

where it is not clear if $e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_m$ is a basis of $\Bbb R^m$ or a basis of $T_{\varphi(p)}\Bbb R^m$ (I know that both spaces are essentially the same thing anyway).

The definition of differential of a map $f\in C^1(M,\Bbb R)$ is defined as

$$d_p f:={\rm pr_2}\circ T_p f\tag5$$

where ${\rm pr_2}$ is the canonical projection of the second coordinate. But here again appear my confusion with the notation of $(T_p\varphi)v$ when is stated that

$$(d_p f)v=\partial (f\circ\varphi^{-1})(x_0)(T_p\varphi)v\tag6$$

where $x_0:=\varphi(p)$. From all the above definitions I can follow the algebraic manipulations of $(6)$ but anyway it seems meaningless, observe that $(T_p\varphi)v\in T_{\varphi(p)}V\subset T_{\varphi(p)}\Bbb R^m$, however the domain of $\partial (f\circ \varphi^{-1})(x_0)$ is not $T_{\varphi(p)}V$!!!

I must assume that here the authors are using some trivial isomorphism between $T_{\varphi(p)}V$ and $V$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $T_p\mathbb{R}^n$ is canonically isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ via the map
$$\begin{align}
T_p\mathbb{R}^n &\to \mathbb{R}^n \\
(p,v) &\mapsto v
\end{align}$$
most authors do not bother distinguishing them. In fact, some even *define* $T_p\mathbb{R}^n$ to be equal to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Similarly, if $V$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the inclusion map $V \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ induces an isomorphism $T_pV \cong T_p\mathbb{R}^n$ and hence an isomorphism $T_pV \cong \mathbb{R}^n$ for any $p \in V$. Thus $T_pV$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be (and in practice, are) treated as if they were equal.

> it is not clear if $e_1,e_2,…,e_m$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^m$ or a basis of $T_{\varphi(p)}\mathbb{R}^m$

It is a basis of $T_{\varphi(p)}V$, which is canonically identified with $T_{\varphi(p)}\mathbb{R}^n \cong \mathbb{R}^n$.

> however the domain of $\partial(f\circ\varphi^{−1})(x_0)$ is not $T_{φ(p)}V$

Again, this is not a problem because $T_{\varphi(p)}V$ is, for all intents and purposes, equal to $\mathbb{R}^n$.